# Insert div into other div with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two pages in my site.
Page one code is dynamic. and there is a section which generates dynamically.

These are the classes which generates for that section  :

```
div.when, div.where, div.planner, div.capacity, div.websites
```

I want to use that same section in my page two inside below div.

```
<div class="add-to-calendar"> </div>
```

I am not getting any clue how can I do it with jquery or javascript.

I need help in this.

Comment: googleing your question title gives an answer. http://api.jquery.com/append/

Answer (score 1):

You can use append method to include any element inside div.

### Html:

```
<div class="innerdiv"> Inner Div</div>

<div class="add-to-calendar">Outer Div </div>
```

### Jquery :

.append method will insert inner div to your outer div.

```
$(".add-to-calendar").append($(".innerdiv"));
```

If your page refreshed, No problem you can maintain element in localstorage. 
    use below code to maintain the element and use it.

```
var testObject = $(".innerdiv").html(); // get the element  
localStorage.setItem('element', testObject ); // Put the object into localstorage
var getTestObject = localStorage.getItem('element'); // use the element
$(".add-to-calendar").append($(getTestObject)); // Insert element
```

Comment: If your page refreshed, No problem you can maintain element in localstorage. 
 use below code to maintain the element and use it. 
 
 var testObject = $(".innerdiv").html(); // get the element 
 localStorage.setItem('element', testObject ); // Put the object into storage
 var getTestObject = localStorage.getItem('element'); // use the element
 $(".add-to-calendar").append($(getTestObject));